# OpenSSL generate key with SHA256 digest

Tags: openssl, digest

By default when you generate `EVP_PKEY` key it will have SHA1 digest, that could be proved by this code:

```
int def_nid;
EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest_nid(pk, &def_nid);
```

`def_nid` will have value 0x64 (SHA1). Is there a way to configure this to SHA256 or any other digest algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure this to SHA256 or any other digest algorithm?

No. According to the docs at [`EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest.html):

```
For all current standard OpenSSL public key algorithms SHA1 is returned.
```

---

If you look at the implementation, you will see its hard coded and not configurable:

```
$ grep -R EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest_nid *
...
crypto/evp/p_lib.c:int EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest_nid(EVP_PKEY *pkey, int *pnid)
...
```

Then:

```
int EVP_PKEY_get_default_digest_nid(EVP_PKEY *pkey, int *pnid)
{
    if (!pkey->ameth || !pkey->ameth->pkey_ctrl)
        return -2;
    return pkey->ameth->pkey_ctrl(pkey, ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID,
                                  0, pnid);
}
```

And:

```
$ grep -R ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID *
crypto/dsa/dsa_ameth.c:     case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
crypto/ec/ec_ameth.c:       case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
crypto/evp/evp.h:#define ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID  0x3
crypto/evp/p_lib.c:    return pkey->ameth->pkey_ctrl(pkey, ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID,
crypto/hmac/hm_ameth.c:     case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:        case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
engines/ccgost/gost_ameth.c:        case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
engines/ccgost/gost_ameth.c:        case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
```

Finally, from `crypto/hmac/hm_ameth.c`:

```
static int hmac_pkey_ctrl(EVP_PKEY *pkey, int op, long arg1, void *arg2)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
            *(int *)arg2 = NID_sha1;
            return 1;

        default:
            return -2;
    }
}
```

And, from `crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c`:

```
static int rsa_pkey_ctrl(EVP_PKEY *pkey, int op, long arg1, void *arg2)
{
    X509_ALGOR *alg = NULL;
    switch (op)
    {
        ... 
        case ASN1_PKEY_CTRL_DEFAULT_MD_NID:
            *(int *)arg2 = NID_sha1;
            return 1;
        ...
}
```